# How to type a^b in org-mode?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, org-table, formatting

In an org-mode table, I want to write 2^3, but exporting to html turns it into 2<sup>3</sup>.

I prefer not to use inline verbatim, and I would like to not have a space between the `^` and the other text.

Is there a keyword I can use or some inline pseudo-latex like `\vert`?
Finally, if there is a keyword I can use, where are these keywords listed so I can look up the next one?

Comment: `org-export-with-sub-superscripts`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @rpluim mentions in a comment, setting `org-export-with-sub-superscripts` to nil would disable the special handling of `^` and `_` for subscripts and superscripts. There is one more variable that is relevant (when `org-export-with-sub-superscripts` is `t`) and that is `org-use-sub-superscripts` which can be set to `t` or nil - or it can be set to the value `{}`.

I find the most flexible way to deal with this is to leave `org-export-with-sub-superscripts` to its default `t` value and instead of fiddling with the value of `org-use-sub-superscripts` using lisp in the init file or with [file local variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/File-Variables.html#File-Variables), I use the in-file `#+OPTIONS:` settings. If I write text in a file that uses underscores or carets that I don't want interpreted as subscripts or superscripts, I add this at the top of the file:

```
#+OPTIONS: ^:{}
```

(don't forget to hit `C-c C-c` on that line after you add it: that will make sure it will take effect in this session - otherwise, you'll have to close and reopen the file). That allows me to write

```
#+OPTIONS: ^:{}

* foo

a^b a_b a^{b} a_{b}
```

and have the first two exported literally and the last two exported in super/sub-script form. The expectation here is that I would not want to export `a^{b}` literally because it is not something that would occur at all commonly. That has been my experience: I have never had any need for any other setting (and if I had, I would change the `#+OPTIONS:` setting *in that file only* to read `#+OPTIONS: ^:nil` and forget about it).

There are [many settings](https://orgmode.org/manual/Export-Settings.html#Export-Settings) that you can add to an `#+OPTIONS:` line: it's a fairly flexible way to treat a particular file differently depending on its peculiar needs.

Comment: I just found this page: https://emacsclub.github.io/html/org_tutorial.html which describes this setting, but your explanation is better. Thanks!

Comment: I appreciate the compliment! Glad it helped.